# Intersecting two objects in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What I want to do is intersect two objects.

I want to compare the objects, and if they have same values on same keys, just add them to another object.

`obj1 = { "Projects": [ "test" ], "Companies": [ "facebook", "google", "yahoo" ], "Locations": [ "LA", "NY" ], "Interests": [] }`

`obj2 = { "Projects": [ "test" ], "Companies": [ "netflix", "skype", "facebook" ], "Locations": [ "sttugart", "torino", "LA" ],` "Interests": [] }

**The result will be:**

`obj3 = { "Projects": [ "test" ], "Companies": [ "facebook" ], "Locations": [ "LA" ], "Interests": [] }`

**What i tried is something like this:**

```
intersect(obj1, obj2)
    for(let key of obj1)
        if(obj2[key] == obj1[key]) obj3[key] = obj2[key];
```

And yes, i did checked SO for other solutions, i had no result.

**EDIT**

My attempt dind't probably work because my object `is not an array type or a string type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isnt really a problem just for angular 2 but more javascript in itself. No angular functions will probably help you here

Using lodash or underscore.js might prove to be more productive and useful

However if you insist that you need to do this in your own way. there are two cases

One is that you already know how many objects you would be comparing

Two is that you don't know how many objects you would be comparing

For case one it would a simple for loop with && cases for logical comparisons

For case two i would suggest you first push all your objects that need to be compared into an array and iterate through there.

Comment: like merging the objects, and than, removing duplicates?

Comment: you could do that as well... remove instances in which a particular value doesnt appear at least x values

x being the number of objects you are comparing that way you can ensure that, that particular value exists in all of the objects (assuming each object contains only one value of that value)

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#intersection

i totally suggest however using functions like this as they prove to be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Use lodash

Here you will find a good documentation:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#intersection

We often use it with good experience